# Retrieve value of a DB column after I update it

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Sorry in advance for the long post. I'm working with a Java WebApplication which uses Spring (2.0, I know...) and Jpa with Hibernateimplementation (using hibernate 4.1 and hibernate-jpa-2.0.jar). I'm having problems retrieving the value of a column from a DB Table (MySql 5) after i update it. This is my situation (simplified, but that's the core of it):

Table **KcUser**:

```
    Id:Long (primary key)
    Name:String
    .
    .
    .
    Contract_Id: Long (foreign key, references KcContract.Id)
```

Table **KcContract**:

```
    Id: Long (primary Key)
    ColA
    .
    .
    ColX
```

In my server I have something like this:

```
MyController {
    myService.doSomething();    
}


MyService {

    private EntityManager myEntityManager;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public void doSomething() {
        List<Long> IDs = firstFetch();   // retrieves some users IDs querying the KcContract table
        doUpdate(IDs);                   // updates a column on KcUser rows that matches the IDs retrieved by the previous query
        secondFecth(IDs);                // finally retrieves KcUser rows <-- here the returned rows contains the old value and not the new one i updated in the previous method
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    private List<Long> firstFetch() {
        List<Long> userIDs = myEntityManager.createQuery("select c.id from KcContract c" ).getResultList();   // this is not the actual query, there are some conditions in the where clause but you get the idea

        return userIDs;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void doUpdate(List<Long> IDs) {
        Query hql =  myEntityManager().createQuery("update KcUser t set t.name='newValue' WHERE t.contract.id IN (:list)").setParameter("list", IDs);   
        int howMany = hql.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("HOW MANY: "+howMany); // howMany is correct, with the number of updated rows in DB

        Query select = getEntityManager().createQuery("select t from KcUser t WHERE t.contract.id IN (:list)" ).setParameter("list", activeContractIDs);
        List<KcUser> users = select.getResultList();
        System.out.println("users: "+users.get(0).getName()); //correct, newValue!
    }

    private void secondFetch(List<Long> IDs) {          
        List<KcUser> users = myEntityManager.createQuery("from KcUser t WHERE t.contract.id IN (:list)").setParameter("list", IDs).getResultList()

        for(KcUser u : users) {
            myEntityManager.refresh(u);
            String name = u.getName(); // still oldValue!
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that if i comment the call to the first method (`myService.firstFetch()`) and call the other two methods with a constant list of IDs, i get the correct new KcUser.name value in `secondFetch(`) method.

Im not very expert with Jpa and Hibernate, but I thought it might be a cache problem, so i've tried:

- using myEntityManager.flush() after the update
- clearing the cache with myEntityManager.clear() and myEntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().evictAll();
- clearing the cache with hibernate Session.clear()
- using myEntityManager.refresh on KcUser entities
- using native queries (myEntityManager.createNativeQuery("")), which to my understanding should not involve any cache

Nothing of that worked and I always got returned the old KcUser.name value in `secondFetch()` method.

The only things that worked so far are:

- making the `firstFetch()` method  public and moving its call outside of myService.doSomething(), so doing something like this in MyController:

  `List<Long> IDs = myService.firstFetch(); 
  myService.doSomething(IDs);`
- using a new EntityManager in `secondFetch(`), so doing something like this:

`EntityManager newEntityManager = myEntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();`

and using it to execute the subsequent query to fetch users from DB

Using either of the last two methods, the second select works fine and i get users with the updated value in "name" column. 
But I'd like to know what's actually happening and why noone of the other things worked: if it's actually a cache problem a simply `.clear()` or `.refresh()` should have worked i think. Or maybe i'm totally wrong and it's not related to the cache at all, but then i'm bit lost to what might actually be happening.

I fear there might be something wrong in the way we are using hibernate / jpa which might bite us in the future. 
Any idea please? Tell me if you need more details and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions are performed in following order:

1. Read-only transaction A opens.

   First fetch (transaction A)

   Not-read-only transaction B opens

   Update (transaction B)

   Transaction B closes

   Second fetch (transaction A)

   Transaction A closes

Transaction A is read-only. All subsequent queries in that transaction see only changes that were committed before the transaction began - your update was performed after it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes that makes sense, i thought that simply flushing the entityManager after the update in transaction B, would have made the new column value avialable for transaction A during the second fetch. Still i don't understand why the first of my two "solutions" works (making the firstFetch() method public and moving its call outside of myService.doSomething()): i still have a read-only transaction A that tries to read the values modified by transaction B, but in this case Transaction A reads the updated value in secondFetch() method. Thanks again.